# creating a simple stopwatch html

Tags: javascript, setinterval, buttonclick, clearinterval

I have been working on this stopwatch now for 5-6 hours. It is meant to be a simple stopwatch html. I am simply not grasping the issues/concepts. I hoping for a little help as all the W3Schools pages I've looked at along with other stack overflow problems have not gotten me any where near where I need to be. I am trying to create 3 `onclick` buttons within the html to start, stop, and reset(haven't even got to the reset portion). The "clock" should start at 0 and when stopped, it should be paused at the number and only started again from the `onclick` start. Reset button resets to 0.

I have tried working with `getElementById` and `innerHTML`. I have gotten the button to work, but it was adding the "result" to itself 1,2,4,8, etc. I am sure it is a fairly simple fix, but I have tried different variations for hours upon hours.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Seconds: <span id="time"></span></div>
        <input type="button" id="startTimer" value="Start Timer" onclick="start();"><br/>
        <input type="button" id="stopTimer" value="Stop Timer"  onclick="stop();"><br/>
        <input type="button" id="resetTimer" value="Reset Timer"  onclick="reset();"><br/>
        <script src= "timer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
var timeElapsed = 0;
var myTimer = 0;

function start() {
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){
        timeElapsed += 1;
         document.getElementById("time").innerText = timeElapsed;
    }, 1000) ;

}
function stop() {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
function reset() {
   timeElapsed = 0;
   clearInterval(myTimer);
   document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeElapsed;
}
```

Comment: You are incrementing myTimer, which is bad. Use another variable to track to time elapsed (eg timeElapsed) and increment this in start() and display timeElapsed in the start() .  To kill the timer, use original myTimer value.

Comment: MyTimer is a string once you grab it from innerHTML, so make sure to use parseInt() to cast it as integer

Answer (score 2):

You should not increment myTimer because it stores the value of the interval you'll need to stop later with `clearInterval(myTimer)`. Instead you should have a variable like timeElapsed as @Programnik mentions in his comment.

Also keep in mind that any javascript not in a function in your timer.js file will be run as soon as it is loaded. This means the `setInterval(start, 1000)` will run right away. Instead you should have the `setInterval` in the call to start. Notice that this will make a new setInterval every time start is called. I'd recommend making a method named tick or something, so that your code functions a little like this:

```
var timeElapsed = 0;
var myTimer;

function tick(){
    timeElapsed++;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeElapsed;
}
function start(){
    //call the first setInterval
    myTimer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
function reset(){
    //some combination of tick and stop
}
```

You may notice that one could spam the start button and make the timer go really fast. This can be resolved if you initialize `myTimer` to something like -1 and then check `if(myTimer == -1)` when you try to start. You'll also have to reset `myTimer` to -1 in your stop method so the timer can be resumed. You may also want to do the same thing in the stop method.

To make the timer display 0 on startup you can just do this: `<span id="time">0</span>`

Hope this is helpful, this is my first answer on stack overflow in a long time

Edit: 
Here's the code I wrote when answering your question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Seconds: <span id="time">0</span></div>
        <input type="button" id="startTimer" value="Start Timer" onclick="start();"><br/>
        <input type="button" id="stopTimer" value="Stop Timer"  onclick="stop();"><br/>
        <input type="button" id="resetTimer" value="Reset Timer"  onclick="reset();"><br/>
        <script>
            var timeElapsed = 0;
            var timerID = -1;
            function tick() {
                timeElapsed++
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeElapsed;
            }

            function start() {
                if(timerID == -1){
                    timerID = setInterval(tick, 1000);
                }
            }

            function stop() {
                if(timerID != -1){
                    clearInterval(timerID)
                    timerID = -1
                }
            }

            function reset() {
                stop();
                timeElapsed = -1;
                tick()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my original code. It seems to work well. What do you think of it?

Comment: @KButler looks good to me. If you want to make sure the user can't spam the start button you'll want to do `var myTimer = -1` and then check that it doesn't == -1 in start. Make sure to reset it to -1 in stop though. Oh you could also change out the clearInterval in reset to a call to `stop();` now that stop is two lines, you save a bit of code.

Comment: @KButler I've added the code I wrote when thinking of my answer in my post as a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable to log elapsed time:

```
var timeElapsed = 0;
var myTimer = 0;

function start() {
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){
        timeElapsed += 1;
         document.getElementById("time").innerText = timeElapsed;
    }, 1000) ;

}
function stop() {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
function reset() {
   timeElapsed = 0;
   clearInterval(myTimer);
   myTimer = setInterval(start, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The stop() function is working. However, the timer starts on load. I am looking for it to start on click. Would I need a set function? instead of having "start" as part of the setInterval?

Comment: attach a click event to the button and within that function initiate the timer

Comment: <input type="button" id="startTimer" value="Start Timer" onclick="start();"><br/>

Comment: I thought i did that as above

Comment: With the code you used, once it is stopped and I click the start button, it adds one to the timer and does not continue.

Comment: Awesome. I see you adjusted your code and the start and stop buttons work beautifully. The reset button however, does not. But thank you so much for your help. If youd like to help further great. If not, I will try it from here.

Comment: The reset goes to 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, or something like that.

Comment: I was able to fix it.

Comment: function reset() {
   timeElapsed = 0;
   clearInterval(myTimer);
   document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeElapsed;
}